# Why this code does not shows images? Java fx

Tags: java, image, javafx, model, controller

```
public class Field extends Pane{

    private Image figure;

    public Field(Image img){
        super();
        setFigure(img);

        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
        imgView.resize(100, 100);

        this.getChildren().add(imgView);
    }

    public Image getFigure() {
        return figure;
    }

    public void setFigure(Image figure) {
        this.figure = figure;
    }

}
```

and the part of controller:

```
public class ExampleController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private GridPane fields;

    private Imgs imgs = new Imgs();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        initializeBackgroundPools();
        fields.add(new Field (imgs.getBlackRook()), 0, 0);
    }

    private void initializeBackgroundPools(){
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<8;j++){
            Rectangle r =  new Rectangle();
            r.setX(0);
            r.setY(0);
            r.setWidth(100);
            r.setHeight(100);
            if ((i%2==0 && j%2==0) || (i%2==1 && j%2==1)) r.getStyleClass().add("rectangle-white");
            else r.getStyleClass().add("rectangle-black");
            fields.add(r, i, j);    
        }
}

}
```

it works with rectagnles but with this Pane do not and i dont know why? :)
(I was trying with empty background too but with no result)
Immages are loaded in another image class (Imgs) and there is no error with loading them.
Anyone can help me?
Thanks :)

@ TravisF

```
public class Imgs {

    private Image blackRook = new Image("file:../../../grafiki/figures/blackRook.png");
    private Image blackKing = new Image("file:../../../grafiki/figures/blackKing.png");
    private Image blackKnight = new Image("file:../../../grafiki/figures/blackKnight.png");
    private Image blackBishop = new Image("file:../../../grafiki/figures/blackBishop.png");
    private Image blackQueen = new Image("file:../../../grafiki/figures/blackQueen.png");
    private Image blackPawn = new Image("file:../../../grafiki/figures/blackPawn.png");
    private Image whiteRook = new Image("file:../../../grafiki/figures/whiteRook.png");
    private Image whiteKing = new Image("file:../../../grafiki/figures/whiteKing.png");
    private Image whiteKnight = new Image("file:../../../grafiki/figures/whiteKnight.png");
    private Image whiteBishop = new Image("file:../../../grafiki/figures/whiteBishop.png");
    private Image whiteQueen = new Image("file:../../../grafiki/figures/whiteQueen.png");
    private Image whitePawn = new Image("file:../../../grafiki/figures/whitePawn.png");

    public Imgs(){
    }

    public Image getBlackRook() {
        return blackRook;
    }

    public void setBlackRook(Image blackRook) {
        this.blackRook = blackRook;
    }
/**
*other settters/getters
*/
}
```

Comment: can you show the code for `imgs.getBlackRook())`?

Answer (score 1):

i ve made this by making package source path and now it works:

```
private Image blackRook = new Image("application/graphics/blackRook.png", 90, 90, false, false);
```

Thanks all anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

Please change to this way in your Imgs Class

```
private Image blackRook = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/blackRook.png"));
```

Comment: If the application is packaged as a jar (which is a standard java packaging format) this suggestion will not work, because files in a jar use the `jar:` protocol, not the `file:` protocol and the `jar:` protocol does not understand `..` specifiers in the path.